# How can i access each element in a ngFor with a function?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I created a simple note app which for loops through an array of objects which holds note data. I have a button which opens up the note for edit by returning true when clicked returning false when clicked again.

The problem is when clicked all the notes open up in edit mode because the boolean variable is shared.

Question is: "How can i access that specific note where i clicked the edit button?"

HTML:

```
<div class="view-notes" *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i">
  <div class="tools">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="openNote(i)"></i>
    <i (click)="deleteNote(i)" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
  </div>

  <input [disabled]="!onEdit()" type="text" [(ngModel)]="note.title" #title>
  <p *ngIf="!onEdit()">{{note.date | noteDate}}</p>
  <textarea type="text" *ngIf="onEdit()" name="body" id="" [(ngModel)]="note.note"></textarea>
</div>

<h1 class="error" *ngIf="noNotes()">No notes to be displayed.</h1>
```

The functions:

```
openNote(i: number) {
  if (this.count == 0) {
    // open
    this.edit = true; this.count++;
  } else {
    //save
    this._noteService.updateNote(i, this.notes[i].title, this.notes[i].note);

    //close
    this.count--;
    this.edit = false;
  }
}

onEdit() {
  return this.edit;
}
```

Comment: can you please share notes array ?

Comment: It seems your question title and issue description are alluding to different questions. Can you clarify: are you asking how you can access each element using a function, or how you can show only one note at a time?

Answer (score 1):

In your title, and in your own words, you're asking:

> How can i access each element in a ngFor with a function?

and

> "How can i access that specific note where i clicked the edit button?"

To answer this question directly -- you can access the scoped variable that's created implicitly within the loop.

This is to say, the `*ngFor="let note of notes"` creates a `note` variable scoped to your to each iteration of the loop.

You're already doing this where your `ngModel` binding is in your `<input>` and `<textarea>` for the note title/text respectively.

You can also pass that variable to functions, just as you do with bindings.

So, you could use the `note` variable to pass to a function, which will be called using whichever note is clicked. e.g. `openNote(note)`

```
// HTML
<div class="view-notes" *ngFor="let note of notes">
  <div class="tools">
    <i  class="fa fa-edit" (click)="openNote(note)"></i> // passes the current note you clicked
...

// TS
openNote(note: any) {
  // do something with this note, here
}
```

That's your question answered (at least what your question is directly asking from the title).

---

However, your question appears to be asking more than one thing, namely to do with showing/hiding *specific* notes (i.e. the ones that were clicked). Please try and keep your questions focused, or at least asking the same question in your post as what the title says :)

I'll answer what I think you're asking, looking at the problem you've described in your question; which I think would be:

> "How can I show just the note I wish to edit; and save/close it when I edit click again, or edit a different note?"

Regarding the show/hide of specific notes; as already pointed out, you're just showing/hiding *all* notes based on a single `boolean` (`this.edit` returned by `onEdit()`) variable, which will have the same effect on all your notes (showing/hiding them all at the same time).

Seeing as you have access to each `note` inside your `notes` array within your `*ngFor` loop, you could keep a record of which note is currently displayed, using a property on your component:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  currentlyShownNote: any; // use this to store the reference of the note currently open
  // rest of component code...
}
```

Then, you can simply check in your HTML if the `currentlyShownNote` is this particular one, and show/hide based on this check:

```
<textarea type="text" *ngIf="currentlyShownNote === note" ...>
```

Then, create a `showHideNote` function in your component to set which note is being shown when you click it:

```
// HTML
<div class="view-notes" *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i">
  <div class="tools">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="showHideNote(note)"></i>
...

// TS
showHideNote(note: any) {
  // if there is a currently shown note, save it
  if (this.currentlyShownNote) {
    const currentNote = this.currentlyShownNote;
    this._noteService.updateNote(this.notes.indexOf(currentNote), currentNote.title, currentNote.note);
  }

  if (this.currentlyShownNote == note) {
      this.currentlyShownNote = null;
  } else {
      this.currentlyShownNote = note;
  }
}
```

---

Or, rather than using the reference to each `note` variable, you could simply use the index (`index as i`) in the array to track which note is shown (similar to how you're deleting the notes):

```
// HTML
<div class="view-notes" *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i">
  <div class="tools">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="showHideNote(i)"></i>
    <i (click)="deleteNote(i)" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
  </div>

  <input [disabled]="shownNoteIndex !== i" type="text" [(ngModel)]="note.title" #title>
  <p *ngIf="shownNoteIndex !== i">{{note.date | noteDate}}</p>
  <textarea type="text" *ngIf="shownNoteIndex === i" name="body" id="" [(ngModel)]="note.note"></textarea>
</div>

// TS
shownNoteIndex?: number; // property to hold the currently shown note index

showHideNote(noteIndex: number) {
  // if there is a currently shown note, save it
  if (this.shownNoteIndex >= 0) {
    const i = this.shownNoteIndex;
    this._noteService.updateNote(i, notes[i].title, notes[i].note);
  }

  if (this.shownNoteIndex == noteIndex) {
    this.shownNoteIndex = null;
  } else {
    this.shownNoteIndex = noteIndex;
  }
}
```

**BONUS**: For coming back round full circle, you can create another function in your component to make your `shownNoteIndex === i` and `shownNoteIndex !== i` (or even your `currentlyShowNote === note`) checks even more succinct:

```
// HTML
<div class="view-notes" *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i">
  <div class="tools">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="showHideNote(i)"></i>
    <i (click)="deleteNote(i)" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
  </div>

  <input [disabled]="!isNoteShown(i)" type="text" [(ngModel)]="note.title" #title>
  <p *ngIf="!isNoteShown(i)">{{note.date | noteDate}}</p>
  <textarea type="text" *ngIf="isNoteShown(i)" name="body" id="" [(ngModel)]="note.note"></textarea>
</div>

// TS
// if you're using the note index
isNoteShown(noteIndex: number) {
  return this.shownNoteIndex === noteIndex;
}
// or 
// if you're using the note reference
isNoteShown(note: any) {
  return this.currentlyShownNote === note;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed explanation. It helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have helped. Don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if it helped you solve the issue 

Answer (score 0):

Your edit flag should be a number representing which note should be edited.  Then you can check if the item in the list matches the edit number and display edit for just that one.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: just assign i to this.edit in the code you already have where you currently assign this.edit = true;  Where you assign this.edit = false, assign this.edit = -1

Answer (score 0):

try calling the function with `doSomething($event)` in the html

and define that function in ts file as `doSomething(event){}`